# SharePoint List Customization - Are Two Columns Possible?

Tags: 2007, list-form

We have an application by which a user can enter the details of an emergency situation. SharePoint would be our first tool of choice except for one critical requirement: As a user fills out a list he/she must be able to keep in view the emergency protocol description, which provides important details to consider when entering data.

Is it possible to customize a SharePoint list such that there is at our disposal a second column to the right of the list of data items to be filled where we can place protocol information so that it remains in view while data is entered?

I have one additional question. Each emergency situation is visually identified by a specific color. Is it possible to incorporate an image into a list template to provide color identification?

Comment: What is the "emergency protocol description"? is it a Web page on another site? A file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible if you are able to use SharePoint Designer.  You would just customize your NewItem forms to what your requirements are.  You can even make them dynamic by using some SPServices magic.

Are you allowed to use SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Hi,

Yes, I would be able to use SharePoint Designer. Now, would the customization of NewItem forms affect any and all lists? 

It sounds like that with customization, a developer be would able to create a template for an emergency (the entry fields for each emergency are different) with the protocol directives appearing in the second column. That would be perfect. How about adding an emergency color? Would SharePoint Designer be helpful with that, too?

Thanks!

Arnold

Comment: Each list has a NewForm.aspx, when customized makes it own copy and effects only the modified list. 

Wat do you mean by template here List template??? if there is nor workflow involved then separate lists is OK or else different content types for each emergency also would do.

Regarding colors , do you need it in the entry form or in the List View ?? yes its pretty much possible using DataView Webparts or simply Javascript. Try using Jquery its the next best thing in Javascript

Comment: Hi iOnline.

I like the fact that each list has its own NewForm.aspx. There is no workflow involved, either. 

By 'template' I mean the form with all the required data entry fields that a high level SP admin or developer would create for use by others to enter emergency data.

Colors in the entry form and in the List View would be great for the users. If I understand you correctly, I should be able to add colors using DataView Webparts. I'll need to look into that. However, I'm skilled with javascript and jQuery, too. It sounds like I can use SP Designer for all the work involved. Thanks

Comment: Yes, based on what you've said so far, you can easily do all of these customizations using SPD and javascript/jQuery.  There are a lot of great articles on how to do these things on www.endusersharepoint.com.  Sounds like a fun project.  Hope you get it working!

Comment: Hi Christophe,

The "emergency protocol description" is text that describes how the user is to complete an emergency form. It must be visible while the user fills out the form. Currently, that text is 'side-by-side' with the data entry fields, much like a floating div.

-Arnold

Comment: Hi iOnline247,

Thanks for helping me get through the "I wonder if this approach will work phase." :) I may be back with questions as I go along. 

Is there a way to credit you with THE answer to this question? I don't see a way to do that.

Thanks,

Arnold